# How to write a progress counter/time for concurrency?

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a very simple `Clock` class that will record the time, amount of tasks, and allow other parts of the code to call its static method `Clock.increment()` so that users can get feedback on the progress. However, multiprocessing creates separate copies with each process, and even if I initialize the class in the main process, the child process has no way to access it. Here is my `Clock` class:

```
class Counter(object):
    '''
    This counter needs to be initiated
    '''
    startTime = time.time()
    currentProgress = 0

    def __init__(self, totalTask):
        # self.startTime = time.time()
        Counter.totalTask = totalTask
        print("Counter initiated")

    def increment():
        Counter.currentProgress += 1
        Counter.expectedTime = ((time.time() - Counter.startTime) / Counter.currentProgress)*(Counter.totalTask - Counter.currentProgress)
        print("Progress: "+str(Counter.currentProgress)+" / "+ str(Counter.totalTask) + " : " + str(float(Counter.currentProgress) / float(Counter.totalTask)*100)+"%")
        print("Expected finish in: " + str(Counter.expectedTime/3600.0) + " hrs")

    increment = staticmethod(increment)
```

I'm calling it like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    example = [1,2,3,4,5]

    counter = Counter(len(example))

    p = Pool(processes=2)
    p.map(conprintNum, example)

def conprintNum(num):
    print(num)
    Counter.increment()
```

And this will not work. I don't want to handcode the total task number to the `Clock` class, but that could be the last resort (violating all good programming practice). Is there anyway that I can make this work in concurrency? I also tried singleton pattern, but no it doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: You're going to need some locking here, or you'll get some really nasty, nondeterministic bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`multiprocessing.BaseManager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers) to share your `Counter` instance between all the sub-processes:

```
import time
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

if __name__ == "__main__":

    example = [1,2,3,4,5]

    # Create our custom manager, register the Counter object with it,
    # start it, and then create our shared Counter instance.
    m = BaseManager()
    m.register('Counter', Counter)
    m.start()
    counter = m.Counter(len(example))

    p = Pool(processes=2)

    # We create a partial so that it's easier to pass the counter instance
    # along with every value in our example iterable.
    func = partial(conprintNum, counter)

    p.map(func, example)
```

Output:

```
Counter initiated
1
Progress: 1 / 5 : 20.0%
Expected finish in: 4.0926668379e-05 hrs
2
Progress: 2 / 5 : 40.0%
Expected finish in: 1.61524613698e-05 hrs
3
Progress: 3 / 5 : 60.0%
Expected finish in: 7.86887274848e-06 hrs
4
Progress: 4 / 5 : 80.0%
Expected finish in: 3.15326783392e-06 hrs
5
Progress: 5 / 5 : 100.0%
Expected finish in: 0.0 hrs
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out in a comment, there is a race condition here, where multiple processes can enter the `increment` method at once, causing the output to not appear the way you would want it to. This can be seen more clearly if we add a `sleep` call into `increment`:

```
def increment():
    Counter.currentProgress += 1
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,6)) # Artificially delay execution.
    Counter.expectedTime = ((time.time() - Counter.startTime) / Counter.currentProgress)*(Counter.totalTask - Counter.currentProgress)
    print("Progress: "+str(Counter.currentProgress)+" / "+ str(Counter.totalTask) + " : " + str(float(Counter.currentProgress) / float(Counter.totalTask)*100)+"%")
    print("Expected finish in: " + str(Counter.expectedTime/3600.0) + " hrs")
```

Now, you get output like this:

```
Counter initiated
1
2
3
4
Progress: 4 / 5 : 80.0%
Expected finish in: 7.12237589889e-05 hrs
Progress: 4 / 5 : 80.0%
Expected finish in: 7.15903441111e-05 hrs
5
Progress: 5 / 5 : 100.0%
Expected finish in: 0.0 hrs
Progress: 5 / 5 : 100.0%
Expected finish in: 0.0 hrs
Progress: 5 / 5 : 100.0%
Expected finish in: 0.0 hrs
```

Obviously that's not good. This is easy to avoid, though, by making the call to increment inside a `Lock` block:

```
def conprintNum(counter, lock, num):
    print(num)
    with lock:
        counter.increment()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    example = [1,2,3,4,5]

    m = SyncManager()  # SyncManager, rather than BaseManager
    m.register('Counter', Counter)
    m.start()
    lock = m.Lock()  # SyncManager comes with a shared Lock implementation.
    counter = m.Counter(len(example))
    p = Pool(processes=4)
    func = partial(conprintNum, counter, lock)

    p.map(func, example)
```

Comment: I thought since `increment()` is uni-direction, I wouldn't encounter racing condition at all.

Comment: @WindDweller See the sample output I included. The `currentProgress` variable will get incremented properly, but what it outputs afterward could get screwed up by other processes also incrementing `currentProgress` or changing `expectedTime` before it can `print` them.